# Searching a sigle character inside an string via Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

With this code I want to check if `str` has `&` character, then return true.

```
if (/^[&]*$/.test(str) == true) {
        return true;
    }
```

But problem is that if `str` is a single `&` character it returns `true` and if `&` is inside a block of characters it doesn't work and return `false`.

Whats the problem? How I can fix it?

Comment: You can use `str.indexOf('&') >= 0`

Comment: !!("adfasd&sdfsas".match(/&/).length)

Comment: @anubhava: no i have to use regex

Comment: Have to use regex? Is this a homework problem? If so, please tag it as such so we can guide you to the answer rather than give it to you.

Comment: I can recommend you head over to https://regex101.com/#javascript and have a play with it. Better than asking.

Comment: Regex is MUCH slower compared to using indexOf. Regex is a great tool when you want to do complex pattern matching, but when you're looking to find a single character, this is what we call overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/&/.test('asfda&dsfa') // true
/&/.test('asfdadsfa') // false
```

Comment: What about if i want to search multiple characters inside an string. each character is separate from others. i have to do like this?
(/&^></.test(str) == true

Comment: for this case better to use .indexOf()

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
.*&.*
```

`.*` matches anything

`&` matches the character `&` literally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). 
If character is found then index number would be return `>= 0` Or return `-1` if not found.

```
var pos = str.indexOf("&");

if(pos >= 0){
    alert('found');
}else {
    alert(' not found');
}
```